# How to detect client's disconnect at server when client power off or lost internet connection in netty

Tags: java, network-programming, netty

I want to detect client's disconnect at server when client power off or lost internet connection and remove is from list client. Can I do it ?

I'm trying some issue but it not working. 
This is my code:

```
final ChannelFuture cf = chc.channel().writeAndFlush(new TextWebSocketFrame(dataSend));
            cf.addListener(new GenericFutureListener<Future<? super Void>>() {

                public void operationComplete(Future<? super Void> f) throws Exception {

                    if (!cf.isSuccess()) {

                        ServerHandler.agentChannelList.get(tranfer.getUsername()).remove(chc);
                        if (ServerHandler.agentChannelList.get(tranfer.getUsername()).isEmpty()) {
                            if (ServerHandler.agentOnlineQueue.containsKey(tranfer.getPage_id())) {
                                ServerHandler.agentOnlineQueue.get(tranfer.getPage_id()).remove(tranfer.getUsername());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only "real" solution is to implement something like a "ping/pong" in your protocol. Basically you write to the remote peer and if the write fails or if the remote peer not respond you will assume it is dead.